# Why does Bitcoin use two rounds of SHA256?

Tags: protocol, hash

Each blocked is hashed twice. Why isn't one application of SHA256 enough?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [Zooko's answer provided in Crypto StackExchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/884):

> SHA-256(SHA-256(x)) was proposed by Ferguson and Schneier in their
>   excellent book "Practical Cryptography" (later updated by Ferguson,
>   Schneier, and Kohno and renamed "Cryptography Engineering") as a way
>   to make SHA-256 invulnerable to "length-extension" attack. They called
>   it "SHA-256d".

Comment: Length extension attacks [are impossible in Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/110065/checksum-sha256sha256prefixdata-why-double-hashing#comment124932_110071) because length extension attacks only apply where the hashed data is secret. This answer is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

My conjecture is the double hashing everywhere was a red-herring to make us think Satoshi was sloppy, lame and take our focus away from a posited valid use case for the `RIPEMD160(SHA256)`.

My lengthy and elaborate rationale is in [my answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9202/why-does-bitcoin-use-two-hash-functions-sha-256-and-ripemd-160-to-create-an-ad/112565#112565) on the related question.