# Bitcoin RIPEMD160 purpose

Tags: hash, script, public-key, ripemd160

Bitcoin uses RIPEMD160 on top of SHA256. Is its sole purpose to make public key address shorter or does it strengthen security in any way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Bitcoin use two hash functions (SHA-256 and RIPEMD-160) to create an address?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9202/why-does-bitcoin-use-two-hash-functions-sha-256-and-ripemd-160-to-create-an-ad)

Comment: The question you mentioned has slightly different meaning where it asks  why double hashing instead of simple SHA256. My curiosity was why use RIPEMD160 with SHA256, for ex: why not SHA256d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RIPEMD160 was designed in the open academic community and not like SHA2 by a NSA competition... one may see this as security advantage.

160bit hashes do also have less space requirements (then sha256) on the blockchain as well as in indexes, etc.

Comment: Thanks Jonas Schnelli, does it also give advantage for being used together with SHA256 in terms of double hashing?

Comment: Most hashes in bitcoin are using double sha256. But an additional RIPEMD does protect against possible weakness in SHA256 since addresses are hashed with SHA256 and RIPEMD160.