# What is the hash function used by Bitcoin proof-of-work?

Tags: proof-of-work

Probably a simple question, but I believe it is important to state it clearly for the beginners like me out there.

What is the hash function used for the Bitcoin proof-of-work? What implementations are available? Any Java implementation?

Comment: Related: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/6037/why-are-hashes-in-the-bitcoin-protocol-typically-computed-twice-double-computed

Comment: Related: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4317/why-does-bitcoin-use-two-rounds-of-sha256

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitcoin uses SHA256d to hash block headers, which is `sha256(sha256(x))`.

In anticipation of your next question, it uses a double hash to protect against length extension attacks ([source](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4317/why-does-bitcoin-use-two-rounds-of-sha256)).

Comment: In reality extension attacks aren't really applicable to proof of work anyway, but convention is probably as good of a reason as any I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

From [Bitcoin Wiki PoW](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Block_hashing_algorithm) and tangentially, [HashCash](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Hashcash):

> SHA256(SHA256(Block_Header)) but you have to be careful about byte-order.

Specifically, [it is `SHA256d`](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Comparison_of_cryptocurrencies)

Implementations are often standard libraries, like Python's `hashlib`.